# How to restrict closing of display alert while clicking on outside of alert

Tags: xamarin.forms, alert, display

I am using xamarin.forms for an Android application, where I need to display an alert with YES on left side and NO on the right side. I can manage it swapping YES to NO and NO to YES, but when outside of the alert is clicked by default it is taking as YES.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

I use something like this and it works quite well, even though it has come to my attention that it might not be future-proof. If the user doesn't click on YES, the display just disappears without doing anything else.

```
bool continue_logout = false;
try
{
    continue_logout = await DisplayAlert("Logout", "If you logout, you also clear the cache of all data. Are you sure you want to continue?", "Yes", "No");
    if (continue_logout)
    {
        // Clean up stuff and clear out user settings
    }
}
catch {

}
finally
{
    if (continue_logout)    
        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
}
```